# PyStreamCallBack object has no attribute length

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Вопрос, я полагаю чисто ООПшный.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку?
Вот код. Ругается на атрибут, а я понятия не имею, как исправить. Если я прописываю атрибут в `__init__`, то, разумеется, он мне и значение потом возвращает оттуда же. Отчасти проблема в том, что метод `process` не может (и не должен) ничего возвращать.
Мне необходимо, чтобы `def get_length_of_array(self)` возвращала именно `length = str(len(array))`

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
import json


class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    jsn = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    array = json.loads(jsn) # type: dict
    i = 0
    while i <= 1:
      root_key = list(array.keys())[0]
      array = array[root_key]
      i += 1
    self.length = str(len(array))

  def get_length_of_array(self):
    return self.length

# end class
flowfile = session.get()
if(flowfile != None):
    flowfile = session.write(flowfile, PyStreamCallback())
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "length", PyStreamCallback().get_length_of_array())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете `PyStreamCallback` каждый раз заново, вместо этого вам нужно использовать один и тот же инстанс:

```
flowfile = session.get()
if(flowfile != None):
    stream_callback = PyStreamCallback()
    flowfile = session.write(flowfile, stream_callback)
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "length", stream_callback.get_length_of_array())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```